# Extract symbols and words, ignoring numbers and specific words, from a string

Tags: r, string

I´m trying to get only the symbol (if exists right before a word) and the word(s) ignoring any numbers and ".docx". For example:

```
9999+1000+57575 red and blue.docx 
58585 +AAA.docx
45 -WW.docx
```

The output should be like:

```
"red and blue"
"+AAA"
"-WW"
```

Does anyone have a simple solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is capture groups, where we capture the characters or words of interest

```
sub("^[0-9+-]+\\s*([^.]+).*", "\\1", vec)
#[1] "red and blue" "+AAA"         "-WW"          "AAA"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.  It replaces a string of digits or "+" followed by a space, or the string ".docx", with "".

```
vec <- c("9999+1000+57575 red and blue.docx","58585 +AAA.docx",
                                  "45 -WW.docx","3333-24 AAA.docx")

gsub("[0-9+-]+\\s|\\.docx","",vec)
[1] "red and blue" "+AAA"         "-WW"          "AAA"
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! What about if we have "3333-24 AAA.docx" and we want to get "AAA", how should I change the code? I just found that I have it also in my data and the code above returner something like "3333-AAA". Thanks!

Comment: I have amended the solution above - just add a `-` within the square brackets.